# Line may not be escaping properly

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I've been working on this for a couple of hours already and can't figure out what I may be missing. Basically, I'm getting a list of all XML files in a folder and subfolders. Looping through these files, I replace a string with another, and write it back out to the same file. Below is the line I'm working with:

```
$destination = "C:\Temp\TestFolder"
$newString = "#NewString#"

Get-ChildItem '$($destination)*.xml' -Recurse | ForEach {
    $currFile = $_.FullName; 
    (Get-Content $_ | ForEach {
        $_ -Replace '#OldString#', '$($newString)'
    }) | Set-Content -Path $currFile;
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is the issue? Do you get any error message?

Comment: No errors, but I don't see the change actually taking place in any of the files.

Comment: `'$($destination)\*.xml'` (notice the backslash)

Comment: Or `Get-ChildItem $destination *.xml -Recurse`

Comment: With `$destination` now known, this seems obvious.

Comment: More generic solution: `Get-ChildItem (Join-Path $destination *.xml) -Recurse`

Comment: Thanks, guys (or gals). It was a combination of suggestions from @Mathias and @ sodawillow (sorry, I can only reference one @ user).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not actually pointing to the right directory.

When you run this command:

```
Get-ChildItem '$($destination)*.xml' -Recurse
```

You're using single quotes.  Single quotes do not allow for string expansion, like you're trying to do with `$($destination)`.  When PowerShell runs this, it's actually looking for files in a path called $($destination), which isn't going to exist.

Instead, replace them with double quotes, or even better, remove the quotes entireley.

```
Get-ChildItem $destination\*.xml -Recurse
```

Finally, you don't need to use a `For-Each` loop to replace all of the instances of that string. It's possible to call Get-Content, then call replace, and finally set the value all on one line, like so:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $destination\*.xml -Recurse 
ForEach ($file in $files){ 
  Set-Content ((Get-Content $File.FullName) -Replace '#OldString#', $newString) `
    -Path $file.fullname 
}
```